# Web.config ASP handler for .atom file

Tags: iis, web-config, opera, mime, plesk

I've an asp page that applies xsl to xhtml page to give application/xml+atom output page recognizable by some feed readers.
Opera particularly, uses file extension rather than MIME type to detect feed!
If I paste ASP into page with .atom extension its returned without server-side script preprocessing! As server is cohosting my site with others, so except adding my custom types for obviously missed ones such as .svg & .xhtml through Plesk interface, I want to deter fiddling with server MIMEs.
Through forums I found hiding extension using .htaccess for Apache, but for IIS all that was mentioned was to use web.config
The question is how do I serve output from .asp address using url of .atom file by mechanism such as web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is for saving others time when navigating through bottle-neck. For forcing Opera to parse the MIME type, place the .asp as default document in its own directory such as /feed/. This will prevent filename delivery within url.
Also make sure to have included
<%Response.ContentType = "application/atom+xml"%>
for Atom feed using ASP, as its unknown when Opera will parse content for link like
< link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://domain/feed/" />